# net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Chrome-extension (dom.js)

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, compiler-errors

I got this error when i open the site.

```
GET chrome-extension://njgehaondchbmjmajphnhlojfnbfokng/js/contentScripts/dom.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

[Eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84w0p.png)

I have tried to look for dom.js in my code and possible content information in my folders.
But the error is still existing for mycomputer/Browser.

When i tried to open the same link in another computer, the error is not appearing.
Could someone explain why ?

Comment: You have an extension video-downloader-plus that incorrectly runs one of its files.  You can report the problem to its author.

Comment: never thought this is 100% true

Answer (score -1):

Go to your Chrome extensions, and look for the one that has `njgehaondchbmjmajphnhlojfnbfokng` as the ID. Then disable it or remove it.